# Induced map on homology of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ by exchanging coordinates

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Note: this isn't homework or anything. Just trying to sort out some basics.

I'm trying to understand some examples of induced maps on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. In particular, say we have a map $f:\mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ that swaps homogenous coordinates, like $f(a_0: a_1: a_2: a_3) = f(a_1: a_0: a_2: a_3)$. First of all, I'm having a hard time visualizing what this "swapping" actually does to an element in $\mathbb{C}P^n$. And how would I figure out the induced map on homology? My thoughts were maybe to use that $S^{2n+1}$ is a cover for $\mathbb{C}P^n$ and make some kind of commutative diagram, since induced maps on spheres are easier to understand.

Comment: First, you should notice that $f^2 = id$ and deduce something. If the solution is not clear you can still look at the case $n=1$.

Comment: @N.H. Okay, I think that swapping the first two elements is a reflection across the subspace $\{(a_0:a_0:a_2:...,a_n)\}$ in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ (so for $n = 1$, we reflect along the line $a_0 = a_1$). And I understand that $f^2 = \text{id}$ since we reflect once and then reflect back. But then what does this say about the induced map $f_*$? I know that $f_*$ would have degree (-1) if this were a reflection on a sphere, but this is a reflection on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Is the degree then also (-1) since we can view $\mathbb{C}P^n$ as a quotient of the sphere $S^{2n+1}$?

Comment: @N.H. Oh, since $1 = \deg(f^2) = \deg(f)^2$, we know that $\deg(f) = \pm 1$. But how do we know $\deg(f) = -1$? Is it just the idea I had in the previous comment? Thank you.

Comment: Good, now you should remark that if $f$ reverse orientation, the sign is $-1$, and if not the sign is $+1$. Since "reversing orientation" is a local property, you can work in $\mathbb C^{n}$ in a local chart and see what happened.

Comment: Okay, I don't have a super solid understanding of orientation, but I know that for linear maps $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the orientation of the induced map is $\det(A)$. So if we view $\mathbb{C}^n$ as $\mathbb{R^{2n}}$, the corresponding matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which has determinant -1. So then does this mean that $f$ is orientation reversing, so $f_*$ has degree -1?

Comment: @N.H. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to edit my comment. I meant that $A$ is orientation preserving if $det(A) > 0$ and orientation reversing if $det(A) < 0$.

Comment: no worries ! As i said, you can try the case $n=1$ first.